# Help with query

Tags: sql, mysql, t-sql

I'm trying to make a query that looks at a single table to see if a student is in a team called CMHT and in a medic team - if they are I don't want to see the result.

I only want see the record if they're only in CMHT or medic, not both.

Would the right direction be using sub query to filter it out? I've done a search on NOT IN but how could you get to see check if its in more then 2 teams are not?

```
Student     Team          ref
1           CMHT           1
1           Medic          2
2           Medic          3 this would be in the result
3           CMHT           5 this would be in the result
```

So far I've done the following code would I need use a sub query or do a self join and filter it that way?

```
SELECT Table1.Student, Table1.Team, Table1.refnumber
  FROM Table1
 WHERE (((Table1.Team) In ('Medics','CMHT'))
```

Comment: Are there other teams? Do you want to return a student if they are neither in `Medic` nor in `CMHT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Mark Byers's answer with a HAVING clause instead of a subquery:

```
SELECT Student, Team, ref
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Student
HAVING COUNT(Student) = 1
```

Comment: Hey 

Thanks :) dint think to do a count.. :)

Comment: o ps thanks for everyone help :) - on another subject how does an outer join work??

Comment: @hdoe123: Another subject = another question.

Comment: @Marcus Adams: +1 Nice improvement to my answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    students
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    students si
        WHERE   si.student = s.student
                AND si.team = 'CMHT'
        )
        OR NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    students si
        WHERE   si.student = s.student
                AND si.team = 'Medic'
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN 
( SELECT Student, COUNT(*) FROM Table1 
GROUP BY Student 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)b
ON (a.Student = b.Student)
```

Answer (score 1):

> how could you get to see check if its in 2 or more teams?

You can count the number of teams per student and then filter only those you want to see:

```
SELECT student FROM
(
    SELECT student, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY student
) T1
WHERE cnt = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with outer join

```
select COALESCE(t1.Student, t2.Student) as Student,
       COALESCE(t1.Team, t2.Team) as Team,
       COALESCE(t1.ref, t2.ref) as ref
from
    (select * from Student where Team = 'CMHT') t1
    outer join
    (select * from Student where Team = 'Medic') t2
    on t1.Student = t2.Student
where
    t1.Student is null or
    t2.Student is null;
```

Comment: `MySQL` does not support `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: sorry, didn't know. saw the question was also tagged with tsql, and thought that a SqlServer syntax and behavior for outer joins would be valid.